# Update XCode 4.0 to 4.0.2

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Do I really have to download 4GB XCode just to update it from 4.0 to 4.0.2?
I updated my device to 4.3.1 and now I can't debug on it.

Comment: Someone will probably vote to close this but I agree. Its a disgrace.

Comment: I agree too. pitiful update process.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

yes, you really have to. Unfortunately, Apple has no incremental updates.

If it makes you feel better, I updated to 4.0.1 in the morning and 4.0.2 was released that afternoon.

Comment: Blimey. Not impressed, Apple :(

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to upgrade you should be able to change the version on your device using the Organizer. If you have the ipsw file you should be able to put the version you want on it.

Answer (score 0):

It IS necessary. And while I do agree that some of the large updates from apple could be incremental, a lot of the changes are deep within the debugger and other areas, so while Xcode is 4GB as one download, an incremental update might only save you a few hundred mb depending on the changes. Incrimental updates may also take longer to create, but I'm not sure on that.

Comment: Incremental updates have their own problems. What happens when a user moves, deletes, or modifies some of the files in the SDK? And does the user have to first download 4.0, then update to 4.0.1, and then update to 4.0.2 (and so on for successive updates)? Yes, they could produce a complete 4.0.2 installer AND an incremental updater, but then those have to be kept in sync, there's more testing, more ways for installation to fail. There's no perfect solution.

Comment: I ususally think of it more like an app, which is really what XCode is. Ya, it's got folders and stuff, but you can upgrade from 4.0 to 4.0.2, then to 3.2 and back to 4.0.2. It just removes the old to replace with the new. I was talking about more of a patch, but it's just not worth it, esp when you consider Apple isn't charged for bandwidth. It's all of us that are.

Comment: @W Dyson That ease of installing different versions and knowing that everything will turn out right is a big point in favor of a complete installer rather than an incremental one. Yes, Xcode is an application, but it generally comes with a LOT of ancillary material that's also part of the distribution, including frameworks, documentation, examples, and utilities. As far as bandwidth, I'm sure it's an understatement to say that Apple pays for its connection to the Internet just as you do.

Comment: I remember reading something about how apple owns it's own address space. Forgive me for lack of technical knowledge, but it's something like they own 145.xxx.xxx.xxx. They own the entire 145 space because they bought it in the first round of auctions back in the early '90s. (As did M$ I believe) I'm not sure of the details, or if this is even right, but they don't need to pay a service provider for incoming or outgoing data. So if this is true, they wouldn't care if it's a 4GB download.

Comment: @W Dyson, IP numbers may be an increasingly limited resource, but it's the network connection that costs money. Companies like Apple don't just pay for redundant high speed, high bandwidth connections with service guarantees, they also distribute data worldwide using services like Akamai. I doubt it costs Apple very much to transmit a single copy of the iOS SDK, otherwise they'd find a lower-badwidth solution. On the other hand, a 4GB download doesn't cost most broadband users much to download, either. Some are inconvenienced, to be sure -- like I said before, there's no perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

File it as a bug on radar.

I'm not kidding either -- I did, and I know a lot of people who did as well.

If you want to make some noise about this issue, that is the place to get heard.